# Файл в IDEA помечен красным

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Создал новый проект Maven, добавил зависимостей, но pom.xml горит красным.

[image: СКРИН IDEA]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

красным горит потому что файл в git не добавлен

Answer (score 0):

От проблемы избавился, зашел через консоль в файл, где у меня проекты и посмотрел скрытые папки, нашёл .git/ и удалил его, теперь всё хорошо. Чтобы избавиться от проблемы, можно было также все файлики просто запушить.

Comment: А зачем вам git был нужен в проекте?

Comment: Может, давно как-то добавил, либо чей-то проект себе клонировал.